# jQuery fadeIn effect animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, erb, fadein

I've got this simple js.erb file with jQuery:

```
$('.hey-popup').empty().hide().append('<div>Hey Ho!</div>').fadeIn('500');
```

**Problem:**
 The appropriate DOM elements are getting appended to the correct div, but somehow the fadeIn doesn't work correctly.
Instead of just hiding the div, appending the DOM elements and then fading it in, it appears to append first, then to fadeOut and then to immediately fadeIn again.
What is going on?

Comment: provide your demo what you want's!!!

Answer (score 1):

Only number, not string

```
.fadeIn(500);
```

From other example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeIn();
        $("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#div3").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2xewbea/

Answer (score 1):

Donald Wu is correct, the parameter needs to be a number not a string.

If you want to have a little more control of the sequence you can use the callback functions that the API provides - these will get executed when the effect (hide etc) is complete. For example:

```
$('.hey-popup').empty().hide(500, function() {
  $(this).append('<div>Hey Ho!</div>').show(500);
});
```

https://jsbin.com/hucaba/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's strange because if I do what you suggest it does not fade in, it just appears.

Comment: It looks to be working in the jsbin example I linked to (sorry if that's a 'works on my machine!'). Maybe it's browser specific or there's something else going on, any other js involved?

Comment: ...and make sure that the duration parameter passed to 'fadeIn' is a number not a string as it was in your original code

Answer (score 1):

jQuery always work with

$(document).ready(function(){

working example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hey-popup').empty().hide().append('<div>Hey Ho!</div>').fadeIn('500');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="hey-popup">my name is name</div>
```

Comment: Not sure that this is 100% helpful, not least because the document ready function can have a nice shortcut... (https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-document-ready-plain-javascript/) but also because the questioner is looking at something in Rails by the sounds of it. I'm not able to replicate the issue either with or without the document ready (https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/trj7cr83/). Perhaps we need more context to answer?